# absolute positioned element not getting 100% height

Tags: css

here's my code (a bit simplified)

```
<thisIsADiv id="wrapper" style="width:960px; margin:0 auto; position: relative;">
  <img src="img/bg/wrapper.jpg" alt="" width="960" id="bg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:0; height:100%;" />
  <some more stuff></stuff>
</thisIsADiv >
```

here's my problem:
if i give my image 100% height it works correctly in firefox/chrome (it stretches all allong its wrapper) while in explorer it inherits the page height!! causing an overheighted page.
I tried with height=inherit but in firefox/chrome image doesn't stretch at all, in explorer the problem remains the same. 
Height=auto: the same as above in F/C + explorer doesn't stretch too.

Any idea?
Thanks 
Vitto

Comment: The code isn't displaying, did you format it properly?

Comment: i guess i did something wrong..going to read rules!!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a height to your `wrapper` div.

**Edit:** IE doesn't like `z-index: 0;` so set that to 1 and adjust your other indexes accordingly, also why not just use a background image in the style?

Comment: i can't give wrapper an height 'cause its content changes in every page and with min-height doesn't work either.

Comment: i use an img because i need it to stretch all along its container, if i use a bg image i can't do that (i think).
also i used z-index:0 so that i don't need to give a z-index to all the following elements to be displayed over the image.
Anyway i set the z-index correctly and it doesn't work yet

Comment: Do you have a live example? Also, the `z-index` thing I told you about was just a general IE fix, wasn't intended to fix your problem, just thought I should let you know.

Comment: the problem with explorer is that it inherits the page height as it was its parent..

Comment: Cool, will look when it's up.

Comment: here's the sample page..i think it's quite clear

http://www.azero.it/check/check.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `height:100%` use `bottom:0` on the image.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify `height` & `width` for absolute positioned elements, sometimes IE is correct in its display, also you think its wrong because of FF & Chrome (they fix you're code):

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:960px; margin:0 auto;position: relative;">
  <img src="img/bg/wrapper.jpg" alt="" width="960" id="bg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;height:theheightofyourimage;">
</div>
```

`position: absolute` automatically gets `z-index 1`.